# Error: Invalid Transaction, Transaction version is not supported while trying to send versioned transaction

Tags: web3.js, transactions, versionedtransactions

I am trying to create a lookup table using this [guide](https://docs.solana.com/developing/lookup-tables) for reference. But while trying to send the transaction, like here
[image]

I am getting the following error

[image]

**npm package versions**
web3.js - 1.70.1
anchor - 0.25.0

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please replace these screenshots of code with text? This will make your question and the answers attached to it searchable in Google for others having the same trouble as you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems my solana cli was outdated. I updated it and now it's working.

Comment: I would upvote this answer if you could detail which version of the CLI added support for versioned transactions as you've tried to use them here.

Comment: i would also upvote if he posts how he got versioned tx working with anchor 